# Yup (with formik and react) - Can't validate array length

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

kinda new to Yup and I can't figure out how to validate that an array is not empty.

I'm using react + formik + yup + material-ui

here is an example I've created:

https://codesandbox.io/s/new-fire-29onf?file=/src/App.js

I tried in the validationSchema to just use the required method:

```
validationSchema={Yup.object({ permissions : Yup.array().required('permission cant be empty') })}
```

i tried to add my functionally using the test method like this:

```
validationSchema={Yup.object({ permission: Yup.array().test ('notEmptyArr', 'array is empty', (value) =>{ console.log(value); return value.length > 0; }) })}
```

i also tried to add method to the array like this:

```
Yup.addMethod(Yup.array, "notEmpty", function(message) { return this.test("notEmpty", message, function(arr) { return Boolean( arr.length > 0 ); }); });
```

But none of that worked for me : (

if I remove the validation I see the value.permission is indeed an array, with values (if selected)

what am I doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can use `.min()`:

```
validationSchema={Yup.object({
    permissions: Yup.array().min(1)
})}
```

Answer (score 5):

#### UPDATE / WARNING:

Previously only `array().required()` was required to make sure there was at leas 1 item in the array. For example `[]` would not pass the test.

⚠️ As of version [0.31.0 (2020-11-23)](https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0310-2020-11-23) the behavior of `array().required()` changed! Now to make sure you have at least 1 item in the array you need to sure: `array().required().min(1)`

Comment: this just working with string arrays? or also with objects arrays? because in my case is not working... .

Answer (score 3):

use `array().min(1)` to handle an empty array error instead of `required()`; if you use Formik to handle a custom message, use `array().min(1, 'your message')`